# Sum numbers of each line with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is when I enter numbers to textarea, I need it to get the sum of each line.

Example of entered lines on Textarea:

1. 10 10 10
2. 99 11
3. 11 11

Example of Div where I get sum of each line

1. 30
2. 110
3. 22

I have a script, but it shows results only with alerts. I don't know how to do it, so it would show all results on div. Now div shows only the results of last line.

```
$('#sub').click(function() {

   var grandTotal = 0,
       rowTotals = [], // array to hold individual row totals
       rowData,
       rows,
       val,
       rawData = document.getElementById('nums').value;

   // if desired replace this comment with regex validation of rawData

   rows = rawData.split("\n");

   for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rowTotals[i] = 0;
      rowData = rows[i].split(" ");
      // if you need to test that each row has the same number
      // of values in it do that here

      for (var j=0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
         val = parseFloat(rowData[j]);
         // add validation of val here
         rowTotals[i] += val;
      }

      alert("Total for row " + (i + 1) + ": " + rowTotals[i]);
        // ALERT SHOWS RESULT FOR EVERY LINE

$('#res').html(rowTotals[i]);
        // HTML SHOWS RES FOR LAST LINE ONLY. I NEED IT TO SHOW RESULTS OF ALL LINES
   }
});
```

```
<textarea id="nums" rows="10"></textarea> 
    <div id="res"></div>
<input type="button" id="sub" value="Sum">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9yc70csj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your function, reset the results with `$('#res').html("")`.

Then, to add your results to the div, use the code below:

```
 var div = $('<div/>');
 div.text("Total for row " + (i + 1) + ":" + rowTotals[i]);
 $('#res').append(div);
```

You create a new div, then put the text you want inside. Then you append it to the result, so each new div will be at the end of the #res container.

Also, it would be a good idea to handle properly empty lines or lines with syntax errors. For example, you can:

- check that the lines begin with a number (to exclude empty lines), like this

  ```
  if(!rows[i].match("[0-9]+")) continue;
  ```
- check that what you parse is indeed a number, using `isNaN`:

  ```
  val = parseFloat(rowData[j]);
  if(!isNaN(val)) rowTotals[i] += val;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
alert("Total for row " + (i + 1) + ": " + rowTotals[i]);
```

Add this:

```
$('#res').html($('#res').html()+rowTotals[i] + "<br>");
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/9yc70csj/3/

Answer (score 0):

change last line to this
`$('#res').html($('#res').html() + "<br>" + rowTotals[i]);`